# 414 Error for creating trigger for google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some exisiting google app scripts in a spreadsheet of my google drive.
Tried to create a time driven trigger under Script `Editor -> Resources` to automate the execution of a script. `Encountered error: 414`. That’s an error.

The requested `URL /... is too large` to process. That’s all we know.

Read through some of the existing similar issues/solution. Nothing specific to time driven triggers found.

Anyone has a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the script without the trigger? I find most times I get that error it's because I'm trying to add a trigger to a script that I haven't yet run and authorised first. Good luck!